# XML file "Imported content is empty" error in sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import an .xml file in a spreadsheet:
http://numismatics.org/ocre/id/ric.2_3(2).hdn.88.xml

Importing the whole file works, but when I try to import a specific item (e.g. //legend), I get an error: "Imported content is empty":
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14uLZ5nTFiTkb4HYQ_a4xjuIgmXbReTPCDBvvTHuqAck/edit?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "http://numismatics.org/ocre/id/ric.2_3(2).hdn.88.xml"), 1000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'legend'"), ">(.+)</"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, how about the following xpath?

#### Modified xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='legend']
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name()='legend']")
```

- In this case, `http://numismatics.org/ocre/id/ric.2_3(2).hdn.88.xml` is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [local-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)